# How can I avoid unnecessary service requests?

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, angular2-observables

I have this code snippet that does some data processing and returns an array.

```
    choose(n?: number): Observable<PickQuality[]> {
        this.championService.getChampions()
        .subscribe(champions => {
            if(this.options.length == 0)
                champions.forEach(champion => 
                    this.options.push(new PickQuality(champion, 0)));

                // Some computing happens, chosen variable is defined here

                this.chosenObserver.next(chosen);
        });


        let obs = new Observable<PickQuality[]>((observer => this.chosenObserver = observer));
        return obs;
}
```

The thing is I have to call getChampions() from my service everytime choose() runs because I need the async context to call my observer's next(). The if clause solved the replication of the content, but I still make excessive calls to my service. How can I make it so that the service is only called once and then I retrieve the data from the object itself?

PS: I had to structure it like this because it depends on async content that comes from a service. Filling my "this.options" property on constructor or ngOnInit() wouldn't work because the choose() call would happen first, so I had to fill the array inside the choose function().

Comment: What is calling 'choose()'? Whatever it is, this definitely does not happen before the constructor! Normally such async calls should go into ngOnInit() and from your explanation it is not clear why it should fail.

Comment: I have a component that calls "choose()". I've tried using console.log to find out when each is called. Even though the constructor runs first I have no guarantee that getChampions() result will be availble for use on choose() function.

Comment: If I run the async call on the ngOnInit() how do I make sure the content is available when choose is called?

Answer (score 0):

If I structure the code as follows, when choose is called my "this.options" isn't yet populated by OnInit.

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.championService.getChampions()
        .subscribe(champions => {
                champions.forEach(champion => 
                    this.options.push(new PickQuality(champion, 0)));

        });
}

choose(n?: number): Observable<PickQuality[]> {
    this.reevaluate();

    var sorted = this.options.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);
    var chosen: PickQuality[];

    if(n) chosen = sorted.slice(0, n);
    else chosen = sorted.slice(0, 1);

    //this.chosenObserver.next(chosen);

    let obs = new Observable<PickQuality[]>(observer => observer.next(chosen));
    return obs;
}
```

How can I make sure "choose" is only run after my NgOnInit runs?